# JQuery highlight table row

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table row which has class='highlightedrows' within my html

I am trying to use

```
 $(".highlightedrows").effect("highlight", {}, 1500);
```

but this gives me a javascript error 'Object does not support this property or method' Code 0 in I.E 6

I am importing effects.core.js and effects.highlight.js, is it because this animate method won't work on a table row element?

Thanks,

IGNORE i wan't importing the file correctly... will delete the question

Comment: What happens if you do `alert($.fn.effect);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just tried it and it works. The only jQuery JavaScript files I have specified are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

My JavaScript is:

```
$('tr').click(function(){$(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);});
```

Have you specified the files correctly?

Comment: Hi Neil, I clearly highlighted one of my div with a class name. But when i tried to highlight a row with $(".table-simple tbody tr:first-child").effect("highlight",{}, 3000); where table-simple is the class of table of which i wanted to highlight the first row. But there is no highlight effect with this code. The first row td's have div in it. And again my table view is very long and needs scrolling. Do you think this is the reason that the row is not being highlighted?